# How to calculate the time to reach a given true anomaly?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, calculation

I'm looking for a general formula or procedure calculate time to reach any given true anomaly.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking

Comment: @Slarty Lets say  I want to find how long it will take to get so that my true anomaly is 270 degress.

Comment: Is [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/23988/how-to-get-true-anomaly-from-time?rq=1) what you are looking for ? The formula is what is given in the question and is not verified, I think.

Comment: @AJN it seems to be the opposite. You've linked to "How to get true anomaly from time?" and this question asks "How to get time from true anomaly?"

Comment: @Slarty I think it was clear enough but I've modified the wording a bit. Sometimes questions don't have to be long. At this point I hope it's clear enough so that closing the question which blocks anyone from posting answers won't be necessary.

Comment: @uhoh The question has time variable on the LHS. And tha OP was asking how to get the true anomaly on the LHS instead. So, I figured, the formula the OP of that question already had is what the OP of this question wanted. That is why I didn't try to flag as duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assumptions:

- The value you are requesting is the time-of-flight from, or to the periapsis of your specified orbit to the specified True Anomaly. We will designate this value as $t$.
- We have the following information:

| Symbol | Parameter |
| --- | --- |
| $e$ | [Orbital Eccentricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_eccentricity) $0\le e \le 1$ for an elliptical orbit, $e > 1$ for a hyperbolic orbit. |
| $a$ | [Semimajor Axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_and_semi-minor_axes) (with the convention that semimajor axis is a negative value for a hyperbolic trajectory) |
| $\theta$ | [True Anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_anomaly) in radians. The assumptions of the following calculations assume that the value is in the range $-\pi \le \theta \le \pi$ |
| $\mu$ | [Standard Gravitational Parameter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_gravitational_parameter) of the body being orbited. |

I have chosen to limit this to the Elliptical and Hyperbolic cases.  The math is straightforward in the circular case ($e = 0$), since the orbiting object moves at a constant speed,  and the parabolic case ($e = 1$) has its own set of equations.

**1. Calculate the [Eccentric Anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eccentric_anomaly)($E$) or Hyperbolic Eccentric Anomaly ($F$) from True Anomaly.**
The Eccentric anomaly is a geometric quasi-angular parameter used to solve Kepler's equations.

| Elliptical Orbit | Hyperbolic Orbit |
| --- | --- |
| $E=\pm\cos^{-1}\left({\frac{e+\cos\theta}{1+e\cos\theta}}\right)$ | $F=\pm\cosh^{-1}\left({\frac{e+\cos\theta}{1+e\cos\theta}}\right)$ |

Use the value of $E$ or $F$ that has the same sign as True Anomaly $\theta$.  At the periapsis ($\theta = 0$) and apoapsis ($\theta = \pm \pi$) of the orbit, or if the orbit is circular, Eccentric Anomaly is equal to True Anomaly.

Keep the value in radians for the next step.

**2. Calculate the [Mean Anomaly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_anomaly) ($M$) from the appropriate Eccentric Anomaly.**

Mean Anomaly is a quasi-angular parameter equal to the angle swept out by a hypothetical object in a circular orbit whose radius equals the semimajor axis, in the time it would take for the object in the orbit you calculating for to get to or from periapsis.

| Elliptical Orbit | Hyperbolic Orbit |
| --- | --- |
| $M = E - e \sin(E)$ | $M=e \sinh(F) -F$ |

Again, at the periapsis ($\theta = 0$) and apoapsis ($\theta = \pm \pi$) of the orbit, or if the orbit is circular, Mean Anomaly is equal to both True Anomaly and Eccentric Anomaly.

**3. Calculate the [Mean Motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_motion), $n$**

Mean motion is the angular speed of a hypothetical body in a circular orbit whose radius equals the orbit's semimajor axis, and is used to relate Mean Anomaly to the passage of time.
$$n=\sqrt{\frac{\mu}{|a|^3}}$$

It is also related to the orbital period $P$, which can be calculated as:
$$P=\frac{2\pi}{n}$$

**4. Calculate the time since Periapsis, $t$**

For many expressions of the Keplerian orbital elements, there is a reference value called Mean Anomaly at Epoch $M_0$, which is the mean anomaly of the orbiting body at a specific reference time $t_0$, called the Epoch. The time of flight between these reference points and the current position can be expressed as:

$$t-t_0 = \frac{M-M_0}{n}$$

Since we are using the periapsis as the reference point here, $t_0 = 0$ and $M_0 = 0$, and the equation above becomes:
$$t = \frac{M}{n}$$

A positive value indicates the object is ascending from  periapsis, and a negative value indicates the object is descending towards periapsis. In the latter case, if the orbit  is elliptical, to get time since periapsis, add the orbital period $P$ to the negative value.